# How to convert soap message in Oracle OSB

Tags: soap, jdeveloper, osb

I'm just starting with Oracle Service Bus 12C.

I created a proxy service that takes in a couple of parameters. A pipeline that moves those parameters to the request-headers. A business service that calls my PHP. So far, the PHP receives the parameters correctly.

Next, I am returning a response from PHP. As a first step, I did a simple `echo "Hello, World";`

Two things are happening at this point.

Firstly, when debugging the app, JDeveloper shows that $body in Response Action is blank. However, in a log action, I added $body. That shows:

`<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">Hello, World</soapenv:Body>`

No idea why JDeveloper doesn't want to show this.

So, how do I get the string part from this so I can use a Insert Action to build the XML response that the proxy service would understand?

I tried these in the log action, but all of them give blank outputs:

```
$body/*
$body/soap-env:body
$body/soap-env:Body
$body/soap-env:Body/@value
$body/soap-env:body/@value
```

Edit: According to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13171_01/alsb/docs25/consolehelp/context.html `$body/*` should extract the payload without the soap-env:Body wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

`$body/text()`

I noticed that the tag is soap-env in the request and soapenv in the response. The $body/* works for the request to remove the wrapper in the request only.